# Cannot show CPU and Network values in onUpdatedWithMemory (chrome extension API)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cpu

I am using [this documented API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes#event-onUpdatedWithMemory)

```
chrome.processes.onUpdatedWithMemory.addListener(function(processes) {
});
```

but from some reason, the CPU and network values are always on 0.

other info like memory and such are available (see example)

the example:

```
    {
   "cpu":0,
   "cssCache":{
      "liveSize":0,
      "size":0
   },
   "id":19,
   "imageCache":{
      "liveSize":0,
      "size":0
   },
   "jsMemoryAllocated":0,
   "jsMemoryUsed":0,
   "naclDebugPort":-1,
   "network":-1,
   "osProcessId":23643,
   "privateMemory":38526976,
   "profile":"Person 1",
   "scriptCache":{
      "liveSize":0,
      "size":0
   },
   "tasks":[
      {
         "tabId":6,
         "title":"Tab: Google Maps"
      }
   ],
   "type":"renderer"
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you using the [dev channel](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index#dev_apis) of chrome?

Comment: Yes, dev and canary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `chrome.processes.onUpdated(...)` instead of `chrome.processes.onUpdatedWithMemory(...)`.

`onUpdated` works fine for me on "Version 61.0.3128.3 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)" and returns cpu and mem values.

```
{
   cpu:0.9976754162800675
   id:121
   jsMemoryAllocated:24117248
   jsMemoryUsed:14283704,
   ...
   tasks:{tabId: 69, title: "Tab: Google"}
}
```

Comment: Thanks - It seems that the fixed the API (for with and without memory)